# What is "expression must have pointer-to-object type" for arrays in c++?

Tags: c++

I commented on the line in question. It makes little sense to me. Referring to "expression must have pointer to object type". I was trying to access my "items" array using random numbers for the index, but it errors the array.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


using namespace std;


struct product {
    double price;
} pasta, cookies, candy, chips, pop, bread, eggs;

//struct sales {
//double salepercent;
//} pastasale, cookiesale, candysale, chipsale, popsale, breadsale, eggsale;

double prices[7] = { pasta.price = 3.99, cookies.price = 4.99, candy.price = 
2.99, chips.price = 1.99, bread.price = 3.85, eggs.price = 5.99 };
//double sales[7] = {pastasale.salepercent = 0.30, cookiesale.salepercent = 
0.30, chipsale.salepercent = 0.30, popsale.salepercent = 0.30, 
breadsale.salepercent = 0.30, eggsale.salepercent = 0.30}

double costumer_cart[7] = {};

double subtotal = 0;
double total = 0;

double fillcart(double cart[], double items)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        cart[i] = items[rand() % 8]; //EXPRESSION MUST HAVE POINTER-TO-
OBJECT TYPE on "items[rand() % 8]"
    }
    cout << "Cart: " << cart;
}


int main()
{
    double fillcart(double costumer_cart, double prices);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I was trying to access my "items" array" Its a double, not an array.

Comment: Don't seed the RNG more than once in your program, it's not necessary and it's expensive. I suppose it's fine if you only call `fillcart` once but I would explicitly move it into `main`.

Comment: You will do well to forget about C style arrays[], and use standard containers like `std::vector<product>` instead.

Comment: If you're passing an array into a function, you should also specify it's fixed size. The only time this isn't necessary is if your array is a properly terminated character array where you can stop on `\0`.

Comment: To properly generate a random double for your price (I assume it should be a positive value) this will generate a random double from 0.0 (free!) to some arbitrary maximum price `X` you can specify. `double price = static_cast<double>(rand()) / (static_cast<double>(RAND_MAX/X));`

Comment: I assume you also know that `double fillcart(double costumer_cart, double prices);` in main does not call your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `fillcart()` function

```
double fillcart(double cart[], double items)
```

`items` is of type `double`, but you use it in the loop as

```
cart[i] = items[rand() % 8]; //EXPRESSION MUST HAVE POINTER-TO-
```

An expression using array syntax `[]` does not work on a `double`.   In it's basic form, such an expression requires `items` to be either a pointer or an array, and `rand() % 8` to be of integral type.   `rand() %8` is of integral type (okay), but `items` is of type `double`, which is neither a pointer nor an array.

The usage of `cart[i]` is valid, since `cart` is a pointer  (when array syntax `[]` is used to specify the type of a function argument, the argument is actually passed to the function as a pointer).

Note:   array syntax can also be used in other circumstances in C++, for example with an instance of a class that supplies an `operator[]()`, but that's also not the case here.

Comment: Thank you! I had not noticed the mistake in declaring items as an array instead of a double.